# vich uploader image going to xampp as temp file

Tags: symfony, image-uploading, vichuploaderbundle

Hello I´m doing upload of images with vich upload and is returning the path name as.

The images were being uploaded and being displayed in the easy admin.
But then suddenly it started to not load the images anymore, and I´ve found that the destination directory was changed to ->

> C:\xampp_\tmp\phpB51C.tmp

my vich mapping is like

```
mappings:
    manchete_images:
        uri_prefix:  '\uploads\images\manchetes' 
        upload_destination:  '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/images/manchetes'
```

the images were appering normally, then suddenly start to broken to and is not creating the file upload file in the public directory

Comment: Could you clear your cache ? could you check that you have enough memory under you disk ?

Comment: @AhmedEBENHASSINE well my disk has many gigabytes of empty space.. about the cache... what precisely are you reffering to? I mean what kind of cache? The browser cache? The windows cache? Where do I find this cache?

Comment: the application cache: just submit this command bin/console cache:clear

Comment: do you have `@Vich\Uploadable``annotation in your entity ?

Comment: yes @AhmedEBENHASSINE the annotation is there... I´ve run the clear cache command, but still creating the temp file... Actually, I was developing with django, and was straightforward... I´m considering going back to django, because to just upload a file with this vich uploader there is so much trouble... and isn´t work... with django was only declaring a model parameter `upload_to` ... as I´m only trying to learn these different frameworks and compare their degree of complexity... django was much simpler!!!

Comment: I can say... that in comparison to symfony-vich-uploader-easy-admin bundle... django has all that withouth the need of so much configurations ... anyways thanks... I´m going to laravel now, perhaps is more simpler...

Comment: As you like anyway I can help you to progress with easyadmin bundle, If you want setthe project onpensource and le me know I will help you

Comment: By the way ther's a demo with easyadmin you can check https://github.com/javiereguiluz/easy-admin-demo

Comment: yes @AhmedEBENHASSINE thanks again for your kind support... if I need further  help, I´ll let you know... for the moment I´ll try laravel just to compare the degree of complexity for the same tasks... all the best !!

Comment: @AhmedEBENHASSINE the git link for what I was doing is [gepes project](https://github.com/adrielwerlich/gepes) --- if by any chance you want to take a look... have a nice day...

Comment: By the way, if by any chance you go through the code and see any flaws, let me know, I´´ll try to make it work here then...

Comment: Could you @Adriel Werlich please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `\` in `uri_prefix:  '\uploads\images\manchetes'` for `/` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstable as Ez mentionned you need to change the \ in uri_prefix.
Second, ther's a problem in your **easy_admin configuration** with the edit form.
you need to use `caminhoDaImagem` proprety instead of `arquivoDaImagem` under your form, new or edit configuration...and the file type should be changed from file to vich_file or vixh_image. ..It's already mentioned in the doc https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html#uploading-the-images-in-the-edit-and-new-views

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Product:
            # ...
            form:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }
```

I fixed your code you can see my  [PR](https://github.com/adrielwerlich/gepes/pull/1)